Mi band 3 steps android
I'm doing my thesis on “Creating secure fitness apps”. My program connects to Mi Band 3, and I've already been able to get heart rate data. The problem arose when I tried to activate notifications for real-time steps - the error “BluetoothGattCharacteristic with the specified UUID was not found” appears.
Here is the code to enable notifications for steps:
public void enableRealtimeStepsNotify() {
Log.d(TAG, "Enabling realtime steps notifications...");
this.io.writeCharacteristic(Profile.UUID_CHAR_CONTROL_POINT, Protocol.ENABLE_REALTIME_STEPS_NOTIFY, new ActionCallback() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(Object data) {
Log.d(TAG, "Realtime steps notifications enabled successfully.");
}

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int errorCode, String msg) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to enable realtime steps notifications. Error: " + msg);
            }
        });
    }

public static final UUID UUID_CHAR_CONTROL_POINT = UUID.fromString("0000ff05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");  
public static final UUID UUID_CHAR_STEPS = UUID.fromString("00000007-0000-3512-2118-0009af100700");

I don't understand what the problem is, the authorization was successful, the clock does not disconnect. Maybe someone who understood this topic can advise me if I'm doing something wrong.
I tried to get the heart rate and succeeded, unlike the steps.
Here is what the code looks like:
public void startHeartRateScan() {
        try {
            MiBand.this.io.writeCharacteristic(Profile.UUID_HEART_SERVICE, Profile.UUID_HEART_CONTROL, new byte[]{0x15, 0x02, 0x00}, null);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            MiBand.this.io.writeCharacteristic(Profile.UUID_HEART_SERVICE, Profile.UUID_HEART_CONTROL, new byte[]{0x15, 0x01, 0x00}, null);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            MiBand.this.io.writeCharacteristic(Profile.UUID_HEART_SERVICE, Profile.UUID_HEART_CHAR, new byte[]{0x01, 0x03, 0x19}, null);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            MiBand.this.io.writeCharacteristic(Profile.UUID_HEART_SERVICE, Profile.UUID_HEART_DESCRIPTOR, new byte[]{0x01, 0x00}, null);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            MiBand.this.io.writeCharacteristic(Profile.UUID_HEART_SERVICE, Profile.UUID_HEART_CONTROL, new byte[]{0x15, 0x01, 0x01}, null);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            MiBand.this.io.writeCharacteristic(Profile.UUID_HEART_SERVICE, Profile.UUID_HEART_CHAR, new byte[]{0x02}, null);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

